# homebrew broken after time machine restore

Tags: time-machine, homebrew

I use home-brew for some tools on my macbook and it had been working fine. I recently put a SSD in my macbook and restored it to a time machine backup as I thought this would give me a pretty good replica of what my system was previously. However, since doing that, whenever I call a command that home-brew installed I am given the following error:

```
-bash: ffmpeg: command not found
```

ffmpeg is just one example. All of my commands are listed when I enter
`brew list` so its not as if they aren't there at all. The `brew` command itself still works (`brew help`, `brew doctor` etc) so that isn't missing.

I still have the old hard drive where it all worked fine. What files should I copy over from there to get my brew packages to run properly again? Or is there a brew command I can use that will fix it all for me? I tried `brew doctor` and `brew upgrade ffmpeg` but that didn't help.

How can I get this running again? Preferably avoiding uninstalling everything and starting again...

Comment: Does `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` or `/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/*/bin/ffmpeg` work? You could also try running `brew unlink ffmpeg;brew link ffmpeg` or `brew uninstall ffmpeg;brew install ffmpeg`.

Comment: `sam$ /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.1.4/bin/ffmpeg
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libx264.125.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.1.4/bin/ffmpeg
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5`
So that didn't work. `Uninstall ffmpeg` then `install ffmpeg` does work but thats just a real pain to have to do for every package that I have! Im really not happy with Time Machine for this... I thought the whole idea was that it backed EVERYTHING up for this scenario :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [packages installed with Homebrew not found after restore](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129991/packages-installed-with-homebrew-not-found-after-restore)

Answer (score 1):

you can brew unlink and brew link for each app.

if its painful for you,
you can back up from your timemachine "after boot".

if you import data from your timemachine at starting your machine,
brew broken.

but after you start up your machine at once,
you will success!

Comment: or you can just do this ::> brew link $(brew list)