# packages installed with Homebrew not found after restore

Tags: macos, homebrew

I got a new Macbook Pro and restored from the backup, all of my packages are in still there and the path is still correct, but when I type a command that was installed on the previous system it returns an error. Take for example `pstree`

```
pstree
-bash: pstree: command not found
```

Someone elsewhere on the internet suggested reinstalling them, but I have way too many packages installed to go thru them one at a time.

The computer is running Mavericks. I used migration assistant to restore from a time machine backup and `brew doctor` says my system is ready to brew.

Comment: What OS on the Mac? Did you run `brew doctor` to make sure your path and the install is clean? You shouldn't need to reinstall the packages - but you might need to explain how you made a backup and how you restored it.

Comment: Have you tried `ls /usr/local/bin` and `ls /usr/local/Cellar`? You should easily be able to see if your brew packages were copied.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From your answer above, it looks like you want to relink all your kegs, which is already answered here:

[Is there a quick way to relink my homebrew kegs?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123900/is-there-a-quick-way-to-relink-my-homebrew-kegs)

In one line:

`brew list -1 | while read line; do brew unlink $line; brew link $line; done`

Answer (score 6):

It is documented that Homebrew fails after TimeMachine recovery a on a new Mac or making a Migration as Homebrew builds binaries for your specific machine:
https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/583

The official solution is to uninstall and reinstall homebrew. Don´t cry it's very easy with this line that remove and restore again all your 'formulae'

`brew bundle dump && brew uninstall --force $(brew list); brew bundle`

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a simple, and somewhat inelegant solution: I concatenated `brew list` into a file called`brewback.txt` then I wrote and executed the following script

```
    #! /bin/sh
    cat brewback.txt | xargs -L1 brew unlink ;
    cat brewback.txt | xargs -L1 brew link
    echo "Done" exit
```

I wanted to do both arguments in the same step, as in unlink then link the first program; unlink then link the second, etc. and if someone can describe how in a comment that would be greatly appreciated, then I will mark this problem as solved.